# Looking for the best way to return pass in a parameter to allow me to return a specific customer or all customers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query that could defenitely be optimized but I'm looking for the best way to add a parameter that allows me to return the same results and pass in a Parameter that would say if pass it in as "All" it would return all WO.BillTo records but if I passed in a value other than "All" it would compare that value to the WO.BillTo to only return records for that specific BillTo Customer.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT  WO.WONo ,
        WO.BillTo ,
        WO.ShipTo ,
        WO.ShipName ,
        WO.ClosedDate ,
        WOParts.PartNo ,
        WOParts.Description ,
        WOParts.ShipQty ,
        WOParts.SellRate ,
        Customer.Name  
FROM    WO,WOParts,Customer 
WHERE (((
        ((WO.ClosedDate >=  @startdate ) AND (WO.ClosedDate <  @closedate ) ) 
        AND (WO.Disposition = 2 ) ) 
        AND (WO.WONo = WOParts.WONo ) )
        AND (WO.BillTo = Customer.Number ) ) 
        AND WOParts.TransferWONoTo ='' 
        and Woparts.shipqty <> 0 
order by wo.ShipTo
```

Comment: It's not the 1980's anymore! Stop using that old 1980's JOIN syntax!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as a "catch all" query. I would suggest using `NULL` rather than `'all'`, but the syntax would be the same. The `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is there to stop poor query plan caching. Also I've "updated" you to 1992's ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax, as it has been around for around 30 years now:

```sql
SELECT W.WONo ,
       W.BillTo ,
       W.ShipTo ,
       W.ShipName ,
       W.ClosedDate ,
       WP.PartNo ,
       WP.Description ,
       WP.ShipQty ,
       WP.SellRate ,
       C.Name  
FROM dbo.WO W --Let's update to 1992!
     JOIN dbo.WOParts WP ON W.WONo = WP.WONo
     JOIN dbo.Customer C ON W.BillTo = C.Number
WHERE W.ClosedDate >=  @startdate AND W.ClosedDate <  @closedate
  AND W.Disposition = 2
  AND WP.TransferWONoTo ='' 
  AND WP.shipqty <> 0 
  AND (WO.BillTo = @YourParameter OR @YourParameter IS NULL)
ORDER BY W.ShipTo 
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning OPTION (RECOMPILE), alternatively a branch statement could be use IF...

Comment: Yeah, there are several methods, including an `IF` or a dynamic statement, @SteveFord ; for something this single a single query with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` seems suitable enough.

Comment: @SteveFord `IF` is still subject to parameter sniffing, because it is compiled at the beginning of the batch. But it does result in better query plans. A `UNION ALL` instead of the `OR` could have the same effect

Comment: Thank you @Larnu and all for the help!  Yes I'm working with a new team that are converting Microsoft Access Reports and had pulled that SQL directly out of there into our new tool.  I still consider myself a novice with MS SQL but in the 10 years I have worked with it had not seen that syntax before.  Thanks again!